# Iterate through a list of dictionaries

Tags: python

Iterate through the list of dictionaries and print out each high school and their types

## A dictionary of high schools and the type of school.

```
high_school_types = [{"High School": "Griffin", "Type":"District"},
                    {"High School": "Figueroa", "Type": "District"},
                    {"High School": "Wilson", "Type": "Charter"},
                    {"High School": "Wright", "Type": "Charter"}]

for index in range(len(high_school_types)):
    for key, value in high_school_types.items():
        print(key, value)
```

Resulting in error: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'

Comment: `for key, value in high_school_types[index].items():`? or better yet `for school in high_school_types: for key, value in school.items():`

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR**

You've made a typo on line 7, which should be

```
for key, value in high_school_types[index].items():
```

**Full code**

```
high_school_types = [{"High School": "Griffin", "Type":"District"},
                    {"High School": "Figueroa", "Type": "District"},
                    {"High School": "Wilson", "Type": "Charter"},
                    {"High School": "Wright", "Type": "Charter"}]

for index in range(len(high_school_types)):
    for key, value in high_school_types[index].items():
        print(key,value)
```

**Long version**

`lists` don't have a `.items()` method, but dictionaries do. When the erroneous `items()` method (which doesn't exist) of `high_school_types` is called, Python throws an error, because this doesn't exist.

Instead, you need to index into `high_school_types` using your loop variable, `index`. This indexed value will be a dictionary and will have the `.items()` method.

**References**

[Dictionary Objects documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/dict.html)

[Data Structures documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html)